# How do I make pwm signals with arduino ide without useing analogwrite?

Tags: arduino, esp32, pwm

Hi can someone help with crating a pwm(or very similar) signal without analogwrite on the Arduino IDE because analogwrite wont work on the esp32.

And without using a library.

I need it to take values from 0 to 255.

I was thinking to use the second core one the esp32 but I have to control more than one pin.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: "Using the second core" is beyond *ESP32 as an Arduino* and the question or your problems with PWM or SoftPWM are not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can create PWM pulse with **delay** or **millis** function. for example:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1000 - 100);
}
```

when you change the delay value, you can change **duty-cycle** level!